# JaxWSPortProxyFactoryBean - Ignore invalid response Content-Type

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws

I am using a port proxy generated by `JaxWSPortProxyFactoryBean`.

I gave it my WSDL file and it's reaching out to the service correctly as far as I can tell. I have another service configured in a similar way that is working.

The issue I'm having is that this particular service seems to be poorly implemented. When I send a request, it responds with a `Content-Type` of `text` instead of `text/xml`. Something is taking that response and throwing an exception because it isn't the content type it is expecting.

After some extensive googling on the matter, I found out about the `HandlerResolver`. I tried using that with a custom `Handler`:

```
public class ContentTypeHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    @Override public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        //many other things tried in here
        Map<String, List<String>> theHeaders = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        theHeaders.put("Accept", Collections.singletonList("application/x-gzip"));
        context.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, theHeaders);
    }
}
```

I also set a breakpoint inside of the handler's `close` method. I can see the HTTP response headers and that the server is responding to me with a 200. So I'm reaching the server just fine, but it is sending the wrong content type. I cannot figure out where or how in my handler to change the expected content type.

I expected that the `handleFault` method of the handler would be called, which is where I would deal with that issue. But alas, that function is never even called. So something is blowing up before I have a chance to tell it not to.